# Using a SQL query how do you grab two separate MAX values?

Tags: mysql

I am using a standard baby names dataset. I have a column for name, frequency and for sex. I want to pull the top name for both male and female in a single query. I can do it easily with individual queries but how do you do this with just one?

```
SELECT names,sex,MAX(frequency) from babynames WHERE year=1973 and sex='M';
```

How would I expand this to give me the most popular name for M and F for each year?

Comment: You need to use `conditional aggregation`.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select bn.*
from babynames bn
where bn.year = 1973 and
      bn.frequency = (select max(bn2.frequency)
                      from babynames bn2
                      where bn2.sex = bn.sex and bn2.year = bn.year
                     );
```

Comment: Is bn2.year really in scope in the main query's WHERE clause? You probably mean `where bn.year = 1973`.

Comment: This works great. And if I were do do this so I have the max for every year and not just 1973 I imagine it is a pretty simple update to this query right?

Comment: @MixedBeans . . . If you want *per year*, you would remove the condition in the outer query.  If you want *regardless of year*, you would remove both conditions involving `year`.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I'm not sure what you mean. Still pretty new to SQL and this is a bit advanced for my level.

Comment: I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get the most frequent name for just one sex:

```
SELECT names, sex, frequency from babynames WHERE year = 1973 and sex = 'M'
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 1
```

To get both names, UNION ALL with the query for 'F' sex.

Something like:

```
select * from
(
SELECT names, sex, frequency from babynames WHERE year = 1973 and sex = 'F'
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT names, sex, frequency from babynames WHERE year = 1973 and sex = 'M'
ORDER BY frequency DESC
LIMIT 1
)
```